# how to call service without using var app?

Tags: angularjs

by this method I am using var app.so I need to call app.service()  for loading helper service.but in my new program I didn't use var app so how could I call helperservice here.
Means I need to change the below code without calling app

```
'use strict';

app.service('helperService', function () {
    this.hello = function () {
        return "Hello World";
    };
```

Comment: what is your new program?

Comment: angular.module('yourModuleName').service(....);

Comment: I have online quiz app.Here in my program I am using modules and didn't use var app.and here i need to call service without using app.

Comment: @Sherin go through [this](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#single-responsibility)

Comment: yeah..I get the answer successfully with help of @Unex ..cheers..:)

Comment: @AbhinavPandey Its also a good method

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about [Setting vs Getting](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y023)

```
    /* recommended */

// to set a module
angular.module('app', []);

// to get a module
angular.module('app');
```

Checkout [Angular Style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y022) for more.